# How to find which version of RxPY I'm using?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

I can't remember which version of [RxPY](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) I installed and the obvious does not seem to work:

```
In[33]: import rx

In[34]: rx.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-b9c56e77da3a>", line 1, in <module>
    rx.__version__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

In[35]: any(map(lambda x: 'version' in x.lower(), dir(rx)))
Out[35]: False
```

### Edit

Also, `help` doesn't contain the version:

```
In[38]: help(rx)
Help on package rx:

NAME
    rx

FILE
    c:\Program Files\python\2.7\lib\site-packages\rx\__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    abstractobserver
    anonymousobservable
    anonymousobserver
    autodetachobserver
    backpressure (package)
    blockingobservable
    checkedobserver
    concurrency (package)
    disposables (package)
    internal (package)
    joins (package)
    linq (package)
    notification
    observable
    observeonobserver
    observer
    scheduledobserver
    subjects (package)
    testing (package)

DATA
    Future = None
    asyncio = None
    config = {'Future': None, 'Lock': <function RLock>, 'asyncio': None}
```

Comment: Have you tried `help(rx)` and search for `version`?

Comment: Just do a `pip freeze` and you'll get your answer right away.

Comment: @zondo `help` doesn't contain the version. @idjaw: didn't know about that command -- works great thanks.

Comment: @mchen - i am offering a late answer in case it assists others. be grateful if you can accept as correct answer if satisfied also. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pip` then just run `pip list`.

This will show you the installed packages and their versions.

You are looking for a package called `Rx`. You could combine with `grep` (depending on OS / Shell). See screenshot below:

[image]